# java сумма элементов двумерного массива

Tags: java, массивы, суммирование

Есть какой-то быстрый алгоритм нахождения суммы всех чисел двумерного массива на java? Кроме этого ничего не нашел толком. Я так понимаю, что данный алгоритм считается очень медленным за счет вложенности циклов.

```
long sum = 0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
  for(int j=0;j<m;j++) {
       sum+=a[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте расспараллелить это дело

```
int sum = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, a[0].length - 1).mapToObj(i - > a[i]).parallel().flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).sum();
```

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую.

Comment: @Andrew Bystrov у Вас ошибка, нужно использовать rangeClosed либо range(0, a[0].length)

Comment: @DaysLikeThis если вы будете использовать range(0, a[0].length) из учета, что у вас количество строк будет меньше, чем колоичество колонок, то у вас будет ошибка

Comment: @Andrew Bystrov в Вашем примере пропустится последний столбец и значение суммы будет некорректно.         int[] array = {1, 2, 3};
        System.out.println(IntStream.range(0, array.length - 1).map(i -> array[i]).sum());
        System.out.println(IntStream.rangeClosed(0, array.length - 1).map(i -> array[i]).sum()); Результаты 3 и 6 соответственно

Comment: @DaysLikeThis соглашусь. Ответ поправил. Спасибо